# Adding Entries to a dynamic Table from a different Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

[image: August 2020]

[image: Charges]

hi guys, I have a list of entries from August 2020 workbook (first picture. workbook = August 2020, Sheet1) that I want to add on to my dynamic table at the end of data that represent my entire invoice amount (second picture, workbook = Charges, Sheet1. I would like to set up the code so that when the September numbers come through I can then add it onto the end of the table, etc.

my code is below, (we can ignore the date column M for now!)

```
Sub Pullinfo()
'Pull information from the monthly data onto the charge loader file.
'1 - Set Variables
Dim lr As Long 'research doc sheet
Dim lastrow As Long 'IC Charge sheet
lr = Cells.Find("*", Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row
lastrow = Cells.Find("*", Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row 'last row IC Charge

'2. Copy and paste

Workbooks("August2020").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("B2:B" & lr).Copy
Workbooks("Charges.xls").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A14").pastespecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Workbooks("August2020").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("P2:P" & lr).Copy
Workbooks("Charges.xls").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("J14").pastespecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Workbooks("August2020").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("R2:R" & lr).Copy
Workbooks("Charges.xls").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("L14").pastespecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

Workbooks("August2020").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("S2:S" & lr).Copy
Workbooks("Charges.xls").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("L14").pastespecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
''
```

Please note I am aware i am pasting the values onto the beginning of the data (row 14) however I am not really sure to paste it on the end of the table and to set up the code so it does that continuously for new values. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something that could help:

```
Sub CopyMonthlyData()
    Dim wb_mth As Workbook, wb_charges As Workbook, mapFromColumn As Variant, mapToColumn As Variant
    Dim lastCell As Integer, i As Integer, nextCell As Integer
    
    Set wb_mth = Workbooks("September 2020")
    Set wb_charges = Workbooks("Charges")
    
    mapFromColumn = Array("A", "P", "Q")
    mapToColumn = Array("A", "J", "K")

        For i = 0 To UBound(mapFromColumn)
            
            With wb_mth.Worksheets(1)
            
                lastCell = .Range(mapFromColumn(i) & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                .Range(mapFromColumn(i) & 1 & ":" & mapFromColumn(i) & lastCell).Copy
                
            End With

            With wb_charges.Worksheets(1)
            
                nextCell = .Range(mapToColumn(i) & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                .Range(mapToColumn(i) & nextCell).PasteSpecial
            
            End With
            
        Next i
    
End Sub
```

*Notes*

1. First set up references to both your workbooks. I assume both are open.
2. Create a column mapping from the  monthly workbook to the charges workbook
3. Loop over each mapping to copy and paste the data

Comment: you are so close my friend, how do you edit the code to remove the top row from August 2020 sheet (so that the data headers don't move across)? Honestly such a relief if I can get this right

Comment: In the copy statement replace the *1* with a *2* so it starts at row 2. That will avoid the headers.